# Add wildcards to SQLite query with parameterized inputs in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am using VB in Visual Studio 2022 Community and a SQLite 3.40.0 database.

I have two text boxes, one for a last name and one for a first name. If they are both empty I would like the database to pull every record from the Person table. If one or both have text I would like it to pull all the records where the first and/or last name (whichever textbox contains text) contain the entered text. For example, If I enter "o" for the last name and "oh" for the first name it will find ever entry where the last name contains an "o" and the first name contains an "oh". I believe the SQL statement for that exact example would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE lName='%o%' AND fName='%oh%'"
```

That being said, I am using parameters since everything I read says its more secure and prevents SQL injection, so my call looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE lName=@lName AND fName=@fName"
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", searchLName)
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", searchFName)
```

My question is, how can I use percent signs/wildcards while using parameters?

I have tried adding percent signs to the string for the parameter (which did not work obviously):

```
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", "%" & searchLName & "%")
```

I have also tried adding percent signs to the SQL command itself (which also did not work, obviously):

```
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE lName=%@lName% AND fName=%@fName%"
```

Edit 1:
After a little more searching I found something else to try, which also did not work (I also tried nvarchar in place of text):

```
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "%" & searchLName & "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and testing I discovered that my original SQL statement is what was not working. The following is the correct SQL statement I should've been using:

```
"SELECT * FROM Person WHERE lName LIKE '%o%' AND fName LIKE '%oh%'"
```

And the following is the code I am using which seems to be working properly:

```
sqliteExecCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Suspect WHERE lName LIKE @lName AND fName LIKE @fName"
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", "%" & searchLName & "%")
sqliteExecCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", "%" & searchFName & "%")
```